# Run Node Server from CPanel Cron Job

Tags: node.js, cron, cpanel, pm2

I have a Node.JS server running on PM2 that's crashing every once in a while because of a database limit, which I'm working on.

In the meantime, I thought I'd try just setting up a cron job in cpanel to restart the server every hour if it's down.

So I wrote a bash script like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

status_code=$(curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null https://website.com/)

date >> cronlog.txt
if [[ "$status_code" -ne 200 ]] ; then
  pkill node
  nohup pm2 start bin/www &
  echo "Site status $status_code" >> cronlog.txt
  echo "Restarting Server" >> cronlog.txt
  exit
else
  echo "Site fine" >> cronlog.txt
  exit 0
fi
```

Running this from an SSH terminal works perfectly; if the site is down, it'll restart it.

However, once I set up the cron job in cpanel, like so: `0 * * * * /home/acc123/fix.sh`, looking at the output of `cronlog.txt`, I see that the script is definitely running every hour, trying to restart the server - it's just that the server doesn't restart.

A preliminary Google suggested that maybe `pm2` wasn't on the path that the cron job runs from, so I modified the script to look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

status_code=$(curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null https://website.com/)

date >> cronlog.txt
if [[ "$status_code" -ne 200 ]] ; then
  pkill node
  nohup /home/acc123/bin/pm2 start /home/acc123/bin/www &
  echo "Site status $status_code" >> cronlog.txt
  echo "Restarting Server" >> cronlog.txt
  exit
else
  echo "Site fine" >> cronlog.txt
  exit 0
fi
```

But nothing changes. Looking at the text file I write to, the script is definitely running every hour, and it's definitely picking up that the site is down, but while the words "Restarting Server" get written to the text file, the server doesn't actually start.

Checking `nohup.out` confirms that nothing has been written to it, suggesting that somehow the command `nohup /home/acc123/bin/pm2 start /home/acc123/bin/www &` isn't running correctly.

I'm stumped. Has anyone seen something similar before?

Answer (score 1):

Found it. Looks like node itself also wasn't on the path variable for the cron job. Explicitly specifying where node was fixed the problem.

Comment: So where did specify where node was in your code above? I’m not seeing it!